# how to remove used Apex True DBlist Pro 6 components from vb 6?

Tags: vb6

I am new In vb6

I have To Remove Components from vb application because it's expired but i dont know where its used and when i remove that components is show me error Can't remove control or reference;in use

[image]

Comment: It's a grid control. Sounds like you have used it on your forms. Don't think the license ever expired, I think it was permanent. Are you sure you installed it properly?

Comment: may be i am not sure for that but my main work to bug fix and client told me it's show error for expire on production

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's how I do it:

1. Open the project .vbp file in a file editor like notepad and find the control name (something like `yourcontrol.ocx`).
2. Use a search tool to find files containing text (I use [xplorer2](http://www.zabkat.com/)) and search for any forms in your project containing `yourcontrol.ocx`.
3. Open each found form in Visual Basic and remove the control from the form.
4. Now you can removed the control from the project.

Of course, removing the control will most likely break your code so you still have a lot of work ahead of you.

Answer (score 0):

Go on Design View and delete the TDBGrid control from the frames where you have used it.
Then go to the components windows and uncheck the Apex DBgrid controller.